# 2 clients with 1 multithread java

Tags: java, multithreading, chat

I have a multithread server and 2 clients that connect to it(both are the same and receive data as an input). I want them to communicate like a chat application.

**This is the multithread class:**

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;

/** * @author Fer */
public class ServidorMultithread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ServidorMultithread();
    }

    public ServidorMultithread() {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
            InetAddress inetAdd = serverSocket.getInetAddress();
            int clientNo = 1;
            while (true) {
                Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
                InetAddress inetAddress = s.getInetAddress();
                //System.out.println("InetAddres: "+ inetAddress);

                HandleAClient task = new HandleAClient(s);
                new Thread(task).start();
                clientNo++;
                //System.out.println("Client: "+ clientNo);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }

    class HandleAClient implements Runnable {
        private Socket socket; // A connected socket
        public HandleAClient(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                DataInputStream inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(
                socket.getInputStream());

                DataOutputStream outputToClient = new DataOutputStream(
                socket.getOutputStream());

                while (true) {
                    //double number = inputFromClient.readDouble();          
                    String texto = inputFromClient.toString();

                    outputToClient.writeChars(texto.toString());

                    //System.out.println("Me: "  + textos'\n');
                    System.out.println("Texto: " + texto.toString() + '\n');
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the client class (both clients are the same):**

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MyCliente extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form MyCliente
     */
    public MyCliente() {
        initComponents();
        sendButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        try{
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 8000);
            fromServer = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());

            toServer = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("There was something wrong with creating a socket");
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        sendButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 0));

        jLabel1.setText("Message:");

        jTextField1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.RIGHT);

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        sendButton.setText("Send");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 406, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(sendButton)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 249, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addComponent(sendButton))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap())))
        );

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyCliente.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyCliente.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyCliente.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyCliente.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MyCliente().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JButton sendButton;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private DataOutputStream toServer;
    private DataInputStream fromServer;
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            //double number = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText().trim());
            String texto = jTextField1.getText();

            jTextField1.setText("");
            try {
                toServer.writeChars(texto);
                toServer.flush();

                String result = fromServer.toString();

                jTextArea1.append("ME: "+ texto+"\n");
                //jTextArea1.append("Other: "+fromServer.toString()+"\n");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("There was something wrong with creating a socket");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I just can't find a way to make the connection between these 2 clients in this multithread.

How can I do it?

Comment: You failed to ask a question.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: I just can't find a way to make the connection between these 2 clients in this multithread. How can I do it?

Comment: Create a global Variable that holds all "ChatRoom" object. Each Client will have a parent class "ChatRoom". Each chatroom will have a array of Clients. (2 way pointer, Chatroom points to Client. Client point to chatroom) Once the Client sent a message, find the  chatroom, and loop through the array of clients to send the message.

Comment: they don't , i think they should not get connected (directly) to each other, all communication should be through server, unless you want to make a Peer-to-Peer system?